# Cannot use string.match in js

Tags: javascript

I have the following script, I need to return the following result:

```
{
      text: 'i love apples'
    }, {
      text: 'i eat my apple'
    }, {
      text: 'no apples on the table'
    }
```

with the following script I get an error.

What am I doing wrong, how to fix it (also another solution without using .match could be fine too)?

Notes: search value could be different, so script should be re-usuable.

```js
let data = [{
  text: 'i love apples'
}, {
  text: 'i eat my apple'
}, {
  text: 'no apples on the table'
},{
  text: 'i love oranges'
}];
let search = 'apple'

let filter = data.filter(item=>{ return item.match(search)})
console.log(filter)
```

Comment: Are you looking for something more like `item.text.match(search)`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use [`includes`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/includes) instead and make sure to reference the property in your iteration.

```js
let data = [{
  text: 'i love apples'
}, {
  text: 'i eat my apple'
}, {
  text: 'no apples on the table'
}, {
  text: 'i love oranges'
}];
let search = 'apple';

let filter = data.filter(item => item.text.includes(search))
console.log(filter)
```

Comment: Yep, and you can also safely omit `return` and braces

Comment: @georg good point :), I  just wanted to be consistent with his style. but ill change it.

Answer (score 1):

You are just there, use `item.text.match`. where item is iterator to your data array.

```js
let data = [{
  text: 'i love apples'
}, {
  text: 'i eat my apple'
}, {
  text: 'no apples on the table'
},{
  text: 'i love oranges'
}];
let search = 'apple'

let filter = data.filter(item=>{ return item.text.match(search)})
console.log(filter)
```

Answer (score 1):

The only thing I feel you are missing is the `item.text`, match is a function on `string` instead of `object`, you want to go one level deeper to match the content.

```
let data = [{
  text: 'i love apples'
}, {
  text: 'i eat my apple'
}, {
  text: 'no apples on the table'
},{
  text: 'i love oranges'
}];
let search = 'apple'

let filter = data.filter((item)=>{ return item.text.match(search)})
console.log(filter)
```